# How does dblink work when using it on remote client

Tags: postgresql, dblink

The scenario is we have a host with postgresql9.6 installed this is working perfectly fine. We have another host in AWS with redshift installed which contains a bunch of views. We are using dblink between these two hosts to query data / bulk inserts etc and they are working. The issue occurs when we add a client machine into the scenario. I have a laptop with the psql module and I can successfully connect to  my postgresql database on the above host and run queries without any trouble but when I try executing the dblink connect command from my psql client on my laptop it fails stating ...

> ```
> ERROR: could not establish connection
> DETAILS: FATAL: password authentication for user " **** " 
> FATAL : no pg_hba.conf entry for host " ***.**.**.**", " username " , database "db", SSL off
> ```

I don't understand why we get this error because the exact commands for dblink work fine when executing local to the postgresql host.

Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Thanks

Comment: please show the query that leads to the erro above

Comment: SELECT dblink_connect('dev', 'host=server_address port=5439 dbname=dev user=username password=****** sslmode=prefer');

Comment: if you run this on same server - it does not depend on psql client

Comment: Like it says, there is no matching entry in [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html). There is presumably a rule allowing connections from the client machine, but no rule allowing connections from the other host.

Comment: but surely that would mean the dblink_connect module is set at session level and not the database level? As I said above the functionality works from the postgresql server host just not when executed from my local plsql client on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, it is not a user issue but an IP issue.

Check your laptops IP, it most likely is not listed in pg_hba.conf

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24          md5
```

The first line is the local machine, the second line is for the network you are on.  i.e. 198.162.1.0, would allow connection from 198.162.1.0.

Your laptop most likely is on a separate network and will have to be added.

You will also have to restart the service after making changes to pg_hba.conf

Good luck.